# Atomic DROP and SELECT ... INTO table

Tags: sql-server

I would have thought that code like the following would be atomic: if DeleteMe exists before running this transaction, it should be dropped and recreated. Otherwise it should simply be created:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    IF OBJECT_ID('DeleteMe') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE DeleteMe
    
    SELECT query.* 
    INTO DeleteMe
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS Value) AS query
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

However, it appears that executing this code multiple times concurrently can cause various combinations of the errors:

- Cannot drop the table 'DeleteMe', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
- There is already an object named 'DeleteMe' in the database.

[Here's a LINQPad Script](http://share.linqpad.net/q9ruv3.linq) to show what I mean.

```cs
var sql = @"
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    IF OBJECT_ID('DeleteMe') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE DeleteMe
    
    SELECT query.* 
    INTO DeleteMe
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS Value) AS query
COMMIT TRANSACTION
";
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 50)
    .Select(async i =>
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(this.Connection.ConnectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql);
    }).Dump());
```

And an example of its output:

[image: Many of the tasks fail]

If I use SQL Server 2016's `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` feature, that part at least appears to be atomic, but then another concurrent command can apparently still create the DeleteMe table between the time this one gets dropped and the time it gets created again.
[image: using DROP TABLE IF EXISTS]

**Question**: Is there any way to atomically drop, create, and populate a table, such that there's no time during which that table won't exist from the perspective of another concurrent connection?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone trying to make DDL statements atomic in this way. If you wanted to maninuplate rows aromically, the database can lock the rows or even the whole table. In this case you're dropping one object and creating a separate object. The database has nothing to lock to prevent race conditions, except perhaps the entirety of itself. Perhaps look at using TRUNCATE TABLE and INSERT INTO instead? Then the transaction will have something to actually put a lock on?

Comment: Or, perhaps, bounding the DDL statements with DML statements? For example, you could insert a row in to a table, specifying a table lock, then do your DDL, then delete the row from the first table, kind of creating your own mutex, on an object that actually persists for the entire duration of your transaction?

Comment: Why not use temp table?

Comment: @MatBailie: Yeah, I recognize this is not the way database tables are typically created. Ours is a somewhat unique use case. Your idea for using TRUNCATE TABLE/INSERT INTO looks like it will work. Do you want to add an answer to get credit?

Comment: @Alex: I need the table to exist in other contexts afterwards. Most of the time, my code will be checking to see if the table exists and simply using its contents if it does. Every once in a while I'll need the table to be dropped and re-populated like this, though. In this simplified example, the table name is hard-coded, but in my actual application tables like this are created dynamically and simply having a table with a specific name tells the app that the data in that table can be reused as a sort of caching layer.

Comment: @MatBailie suggestion is the way to go in your case then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem I see you encountering, is that by dropping the object you want to lock *(you can lock an object, but not a 'name' of an object)* you have nothing to lock.

Proposals that involve finding something else to lock only resolve half the issue; the process stops racing itself, but then any other process that references the `DeleteMe` table *can* still race with this process.

- 10x the process referenced in the question, using `sp_getapplock`, for example
- Those 10 concurrent instances of the process no longer race each other
- Then 1x another process that only uses `SELECT * FROM DeleteMe` but not `sp_getapplock`
- That process CAN fail due to racing with the currently Active DROP/SELECT INTO process

That leads me to conclude that NOT dropping objects is better, so that the table in use remains in existence and CAN be locked...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    TRUNCATE TABLE DeleteMe
    
    INSERT INTO DeleteMe SELECT 1 AS Value
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The `TRUNCATE` implicitly takes a table lock, and a secondary process that reads from this table ***never*** sees it as empty.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to atomically drop, create, and populate a table, such that there's no time during which that table won't exist from the perspective of another concurrent connection?

Sure.  It's just like any transaction: you have to take an inconsistent lock on the very first statement.  In your transaction two sessions can run `IF OBJECT_ID('DeleteMe') IS NOT NULL` at the same time.  Then they both try to drop the object, and only one succeeds.

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` also performs the existence check before taking the exclusive schema lock on the object that would be necessary to drop it.

A simple and reliable way to get an exclusive lock is to use [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

eg

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    exec sp_getapplock 'dropandcreate_DeleteMe', 'exclusive'
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DeleteMe
    
    SELECT query.* 
    INTO DeleteMe
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS Value) AS query
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I like this.  It should also be noted, however, that another process that reads from `DeleteMe`, but doesn't take this applock, can still get caught in a race condition.  I think that's unavoidable, so not a deficit in the answer, but a deficit in the design pattern this attempts to help 'fix'.

Comment: A reader would block the DROP TABLE and be blocked from reading the new table until commit.

Comment: Not if the reader process doesn't request the lock used in this code.  It is possible for one of these drop-and-recreate processes to begin, take the lock, drop the table and then Before the new table exists a separate read only process (one which doesn't request the lock) attempt to read from the table.  To prevent that the read only processes would also need to request the same lock, forcing ALL activity on this table to be sequential and forbidding all concurrency (even multiple read only processes would have to be sequential access).

Comment: After the DROP TABLE a reading session will be blocked by the metadata locks for the dropped-but-not-committed DROP TABLE.  And it will remain blocked until COMMIT.  This is the same as the create table-load-drop-rename transaction that SSMS uses to implement table schema changes that can't use a simple ALTER TABLE.

Comment: I'll yield to your expertise in this. Thanks for the clarification. Out of interest, why does that block a read, but not a separate DROP?  (My understanding of what you've said would have lead me to conclude the OP wouldn't see the symptoms originally described.). Is it something along the lines of 'it was blocked, but when the blocking transaction committed, the table that Was locked has now been dropped, and the previously blocked process doesn't recheck to find the new table, which happens to have the same name, but is a different object'?

Comment: It looks like DROP TABLE and DROP TABLE IF EXISTS both perform an existence check without exclusive locking.